# "while" and punctuation to indicate contrast

Tags: usage, style

Are the following sentences okay? If any one is incorrect, please indicate why:

> a. The lion symbolizes strength, while the lamb, gentleness.

> b. The lion symbolizes strength; the lamb, gentleness.

> c. The lion symbolizes strength, the lamb, gentleness.

Answer (score 1):

a and b are both correct. c is technically incorrect, because the fist comma should be a semicolon, in short it should be b as that is the only difference. However, many native speakers might get this wrong, and in many contexts it will not matter.

The repeated verb "symbolizes" is very properly omitted in this parallel construction.

Comment: I happen to hold a different view on b and c. I think c is fine, especially technically speaking. It is an example of an absolute construction. People who get it wrong write it like b.